# Importance of git version

Tags: git, version

I am trying to find out what the importance of the version of git is and don't have too much experience working with it.

Two questions:

1. When working in a team, is it problematic to work with varying versions of git?
2. Can a remote project have a different version of git than a local clone of the repo?

Every answer is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Git folks work pretty hard at maintaining backwards compatibility, and as [phd answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66243767/1256452), you can generally mix-and-match repositories and Git versions.

The big stumbling block you'll run into is that Git *tutorials* and *help* may assume Git version 2.17 or later, for instance.  If someone says to use `git switch`, they're referring to Git 2.23 or later.  If someone describes how to use `git worktree add`, they're referring to Git 2.5 or later (preferably 2.15 or later).  Some commands simply don't *exist* in the older Git versions, and others don't work as well, or do not support some option you might want.

As a sort of general rule, if your Git version is 15 or 20 or more minor versions old, it's probably time to upgrade.  The current releases are 2.30 so anything before 2.15 or so is kind of crying out for being updated.

Answer (score 1):

> When working in a team, is it problematic to work with varying versions of git?

Not at all.

> Can a remote project have a different version of git than a local clone of the repo?

Sure, no problem.

My personal example: I have a number of servers at my job with git version 1.8.8.3. I also have a number of servers and a notebook with git 2.20.1. I work with all of them from the notebook.

Comment: If the setup of the repos is not using anything bleeding edge, then both answers are like what phd is saying.... **however**, git is going under heavy work in terms of moving into sha256 as a hashing algorithm.... you might get problems related to versions if one repo is taking advantage of it and an older client tries to access it. https://git-scm.com/docs/hash-function-transition/